# Using libiptc library C/C++

Tags: iptables, c

Need some help:

1. install `libiptc`
2. commandline to compile with `libiptc`
3. a very simple example would be welcome!

I have seen [the official website](https://www.tldp.org) but there is not many information for Ubuntu and their guide is almost outdated.

I have Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver installed on my computer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As search on [https://packages.ubuntu.com says](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=libiptc) - you should install both source and binary packages:

```
sudo apt install libiptc0 libiptc-dev
```

and then consult [with documentation from its site (netfilter.org)](https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-4.html) to write an example.

Comment: and to compile code, what are the arguments to be provided to gcc ?

Comment: Something like `pkg-config --cflags libiptc`.

Comment: both of `libiptc `and `libiptc-dev` could not be located.

`apt-cache search libiptc` returns the following packages:
iptables-dev 
libiptcdata-bin
libiptcdata-doc
libiptcdata0 
libiptcdata0-dbg 
libiptcdata0-dev (which I installed).


`pkg-config --cflags libiptc` returns empty line


.Now what I do?

Comment: You marked your question as 18.04. What is your Ubuntu version, then?

Comment: I do not get your question. I  mentioned that I have Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

Comment: i was stuck on it for sometime as well, then released that libiptc.h is in iptables-dev, so installing it fulfilled the dependency requirement for me . I am using  Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS .